# Cannot set property 'value' of null" (audio player)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an audio player for my website. I found a tutorial online and on their website it works but when I try to use it for mine, it does not. I've gotten to the point where I just copied the code from the demo site, and it still wouldn't work. Please Help Me.

[in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFpxp.png)

```js
var songs = ["https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3", "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3", "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3", "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-4.mp3", "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-5.mp3"];
var songTitle = document.getElementById('songTitle');
var songSlider = document.getElementById('songSlider');
var currentTime = document.getElementById('currentTime');
var duration = document.getElementById('duration');
var volumeSlider = document.getElementById('volumeSlider');
var nextSongTitle = document.getElementById('nextSongTitle');
var song = new Audio();
var currentSong = 0;
window.onload = loadSong;

function loadSong() {
  song.src = songs[currentSong];
  songTitle.textContent = (currentSong + 1) + ". " + songs[currentSong];
  nextSongTitle.innerHTML = "<b>Next Song: </b>" + songs[currentSong + 1 % songs.length];
  song.playbackRate = 1;
  song.volume = volumeSlider.value;
  song.play();
  setTimeout(showDuration, 1000);
}
setInterval(updateSongSlider, 1000);

function updateSongSlider() {
  var c = Math.round(song.currentTime);
  songSlider.value = c;
  currentTime.textContent = convertTime(c);
  if (song.ended) {
    next();
  }
}

function convertTime(secs) {
  var min = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  var sec = secs % 60;
  min = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : min;
  sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;
  return (min + ":" + sec);
}

function showDuration() {
  var d = Math.floor(song.duration);
  songSlider.setAttribute("max", d);
  duration.textContent = convertTime(d);
}

function playOrPauseSong(img) {
  song.playbackRate = 1;
  if (song.paused) {
    song.play();
    img.src = "images/pause.png";
  } else {
    song.pause();
    img.src = "images/play.png";
  }
}

function next() {
  currentSong = currentSong + 1 % songs.length;
  loadSong();
}

function previous() {
  currentSong--;
  currentSong = (currentSong < 0) ? songs.length - 1 : currentSong;
  loadSong();
}

function seekSong() {
  song.currentTime = songSlider.value;
  currentTime.textContent = convertTime(song.currentTime);
}

function adjustVolume() {
  song.volume = volumeSlider.value;
}

function increasePlaybackRate() {
  songs.playbackRate += 0.5;
}

function decreasePlaybackRate() {
  songs.playbackRate -= 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-player-cont">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/audio-player.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="player">
    <div id="songTitle" class="song-title">My Song title will goes here My Song title will goes here My Song title will goes here</div>
    <input id="songSlider" class="song-slider" type="range" min="0" step="1" onchange="seekSong()" />
    <div>
      <div id="currentTime" class="current-time">00:00</div>
      <div id="duration" class="duration">00:00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="controllers">
      <img src="images/previous.png" width="30px" onclick="previous();" />
      <img src="images/backward.png" width="30px" onclick="decreasePlaybackRate();" />
      <img src="images/pause.png" width="40px" onclick="playOrPauseSong(this);" />
      <img src="images/forward.png" width="30px" onclick="increasePlaybackRate();" />
      <img src="images/next.png" width="30px" onclick="next();" />
      <img src="images/volume-down.png" width="15px" />
      <input id="volumeSlider" class="volume-slider" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" onchange="adjustVolume()" />
      <img src="images/volume-up.png" width="15px" style="margin-left:2px;" />
    </div>
    <div id="nextSongTitle" class="song-title"><b>Next Song :</b>Next song title goes here...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is that you run the JS code _before_ HTML. So you select `volumeSlider` before it exists in the DOM. Just run the script right before the end of the `</body>` and it should be fine.

Comment: The Code snippet is works for me in chrome.

Comment: Yes, because the snippet loads the JS as it should be. I made the snippet from OP's code. But OP doesn't execute their code in that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you run the JS code before HTML. So you select volumeSlider before it exists in the DOM. Just run the script right before the end of the  and it should be fine.

Instead of doing this :

```
<head>
    <script>
       document.getElementById('volumeSlider') // <-- won't find the element (null)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <input id="volumeSlider" />
</body>
```

Do this :

```
<head>

</head>
<body>
     <input id="volumeSlider" />
    <script>
       document.getElementById('volumeSlider') // <-- Will find the element because it's created before
    </script>
</body>
```